# MySQL, incrementing a row count by ascending dates (simple?)

Tags: mysql, date, count, increment

I normally work in Access but cannot figure this logic within it. I'm now branching to MySQL in hopes i can do this.

Have table Visits with CUSTOMERID, VISITDATE

---

```
CUSTOMERID        VISITDATE
  1001            7/6/2015    
  2315            9/1/2015
  2315            12/30/2014
  9851            5/5/2013
  9851            1/7/2014
  9851            3/21/2014
```

I'd like to add a column called 'Visit Number' so I can label in ascending order each Customer's visitdate as his first, second, etc...

### It would look like:

```
CUSTOMERID        VISITDATE      VISITNUMBER
  1001            7/6/2015            1
  2315            9/1/2015            1
  2315            12/30/2014          2
  9851            5/5/2013            1
  9851            1/7/2014            2
  9851            3/21/2014           3
```

It's an incrementation based on the ascending dates, but also grouped by CUSTOMERID.

Would seriously appreciate any tips on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So you have a query that you use to update your date whenever someone visits.

You want to cause an additional action at this point because this equates to an increment of visits.

if I'm not incorrect, a simple bundle of:

```
YOUR UPDATE SQL;
UPDATE mytable 
SET visitnumber = visitnumber + 1 
WHERE customerid = (the id of the user you are updating);
```